# getting too many errors of type " multiple markers at this line"

Tags: android

here is the code:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancel clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    }
}
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items , itemsChecked,
        new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), items[which]+ (isChecked ? "checked!" : "unchecked!"),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

i am getting a number of curly braces related errors though code seems correct to me.. please help!!

Comment: hey you cna ask your code/logic related query here. and you can use ctrl+i to check intendatations

Comment: Since how long you have been developing applications?

Comment: @Mr.777 obviously since 6 minutes ago :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add one simple bracket ')' at your last line.

```
});
```

See below

```
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items , itemsChecked,
        new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), items[which]+ (isChecked ? "checked!" : "unchecked!"),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: Mam, he has still kept one extra '}'... please check again and update code.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancel clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);



builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items , itemsChecked,
        new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), items[which]+ (isChecked ? "checked!" : "unchecked!"),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
}
```

Comment: Did you forget a closing bracket here for the onClick()?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this....

```
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items , itemsChecked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), items[which]+ (isChecked ? "checked!" : "unchecked!"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancel clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();<//here you missed to call show method

    }
}

builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items , itemsChecked,
        new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), items[which]+ (isChecked ? "checked!" : "unchecked!"),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});//here to add ')' before semicolon
```